# Creating anti-symmetrized boson states under general pair particle permutations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-statistics

Consider a two-boson system, each with creation and annihilation operators satisfying $[a_{x,s},a^{\dagger}_{y,p}]=\delta_{x,y}\delta_{s,p}$, where $x,y$ are position coordinates of the particle and $s,p$ an internal degree of freedom such as spin projection. Imagine we aim at constructing an anti-symmetric state of the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x,s;x,p\rangle - |x,p;x,s\rangle),
\end{eqnarray}
that is, even when both particles are bosonic, we want to prepare an antisymmetric state under exchange of both. This can only be accomplished if we define our full Hilbert space as the outer product of two individual Hilbert spaces, one for each boson $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$, and we define creation operators that act explicitly on each space separately $a_{A,x,s}^\dagger=a_{x,s}^\dagger \otimes I$ and $a_{B,x,s}^\dagger=I\otimes a_{x,s}^\dagger$, because otherwise the above state is identically zero due to the commutation relations.

The questions are: (i) Is this a true valid way to represent the state in second quantized form? Normally, the bosonic field $a^{\dagger}_{x,s}$ should not distinguish between particles A or B because they must be indistinguishable. However, written in the form above, the state is anti-symmetric under particle exchange, rather than symmetric as one would expect for a bosonic system. Such antisymmetric bosonic state have been engineered in the study of quantum walks of particles with different statistics, see [this work on quantum random walks on the line.](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.74.042304#:%7E:text=We%20introduce%20the%20concept%20of%20a%20quantum%20walk,interesting%20modifications%20on%20quantum%20walks%20with%20single%20particles.)

(ii) Is it possible to extend the above treatment to more than two-particles? i.e. with 3-bosons, creating a fully anti-symmetric state under any permutation of particles, even though the fields used for it are bosonic. Also, in that case one would need to consider a full Hilbert space of the form $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B\otimes \mathcal{H}_C$.